# PHP JSON Post Format?

Tags: php, json, curl

i´m struggling atm with the simple action of sending the json data from the enfmp tagger to the echonest-server.

PHP Code

```
$file =file_get_contents('./test.json');
$jsondecode = json_decode($file,true );
foreach($jsondecode as $puffer) {
  $result = $puffer['code'];
}
$post = array(
 "api_key"=>"=MYAPIKEY",
 "version"=>"=3.15",
 "code"=>"=$result",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://developer.echonest.com/api/v4/song/identify");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'));

$json_response = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode($json_response, true);
```

The Response is

```
 ["response"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["status"]=>
     array(3) {
       ["version"]=>
       string(3) "4.2"
       ["code"]=>
       int(1)
       ["message"]=>
       string(22) "1|Invalid key: Unknown"
     }
   }
 }
```

The API Key works properly.
Can someone look over the code and give me some hints or examples?

greetings :)

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your code. Judging by the response message you receive I'd say the service is expecting you to send the key some other way. Maybe as a GET parameter, not as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or maybe with a name other than `"api_key"`.

Comment: http://developer.echonest.com/raw_tutorials/responses.html pretty much confirms that `api_key` needs to be a GET parameter...